# how to create/use variables in BPEL process using jdeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper, bpel

I am creating simple BPEL process using Jdeveloper,and want to include all features of BPEL on small level.

when I am using assign attribute and creating expression then setting the input variables with concatenation ((11002) as input then AO11002 will be output), and then setting it in same variable(inout variable). and on next step when I am using Java Embed activity and trying to get the same variable, its showing me the null only,

please help me and guide me for how to create varibles and use in the application also.
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

you can add variables by clicking on '(x)' at the left side of a block. The tooltip should guide you to the right dialog. To access a variable in the java activity, use the 'setVariableData()' and 'getVariableData()' functions.

Comment: thanks, I got the solution. now I am creating BPEL human workflow iterface as a java utility using worlist API,  I have created function for getting taskdetails, query task, but not able to create a task in BPEL through this utility(initiate task) , the problem is we need to create a payload and pass it as a parameter while creating task, I am not able to create payload, will you please tell me what is the taskdefinition URI and ID for a BPEL process.